# Lidgren network, can't get it to connect

Tags: c#, networking

I'm having trouble getting my client to connect to my server in my lindgren network test.
I've tried multiple ways of connecting but it always stops when I try to connect.
Sorry if this is a broad question, but what am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static NetPeerConfiguration serverconfig;
    static NetPeerConfiguration clientconfig;
    static NetServer server;
    static NetClient client;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = "LidgrenNetworkTest";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("LidgrenNetworkTest console initialized.");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write("Color codes: ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.Write("System ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write("Input ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("Sent ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.Write("Received");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Configuring server...");
        serverconfig = new NetPeerConfiguration("LidgrenNetworkTest");
        serverconfig.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval);
        serverconfig.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryRequest);
        serverconfig.LocalAddress = NetUtility.Resolve("localhost");
        serverconfig.Port = 8080;
        Console.WriteLine("Server configured.");

        Console.WriteLine("Configuring client...");
        clientconfig = new NetPeerConfiguration("LidgrenNetworkTest");
        clientconfig.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryResponse);
        Console.WriteLine("Client configured.");

        Console.WriteLine("Initializing server...");
        server = new NetServer(serverconfig);
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server initialized.");

        Console.WriteLine("Initializing client...");
        client = new NetClient(clientconfig);
        client.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Client initialized.");

        Thread serverthread = new Thread(StartServer);
        serverthread.Start();

        StartClient();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting client to server...");
        //client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(NetUtility.Resolve("localhost"), 8080));
        client.DiscoverLocalPeers(8080);

        AcceptConsoleInput();
    }

    static void StartServer()
    {
        NetIncomingMessage message;

        while ((message = server.ReadMessage()) != null)
        {
            switch (message.MessageType)
            {
                case NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryRequest:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Server) Got request from client.");
                    NetOutgoingMessage response = server.CreateMessage();
                    response.Write((byte)1); // Do I need to do this?
                    server.SendDiscoveryResponse(response, message.SenderEndPoint);
                    break;
                case NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Server) Connection accepted.");
                    message.SenderConnection.Approve();
                    break;
                case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Server) Debug: " + message.ReadString());
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Server) Unrecognized message type! (" + message.MessageType + ")");
                    break;
            }
            server.Recycle(message);
        }
    }

    static void StartClient()
    {
        NetIncomingMessage message;

        while ((message = server.ReadMessage()) != null)
        {
            switch (message.MessageType)
            {
                case NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryResponse:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Client) Got response from server.");
                    client.Connect(message.SenderEndPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine("(Client) Attempting to connect to server...");
                    break;
                case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Client) Debug: " + message.ReadString());
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("(Client) Unrecognized message type! (" + message.MessageType + ")");
                    break; 
            }
            client.Recycle(message);
        }
    }

    static void AcceptConsoleInput()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            // Send input from client to server.
        }

        AcceptConsoleInput();
    }
}
```

Also, where it gets stuck:
[image: The console]

Comment: Do the samples provided work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I just compiled the Chat sample and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you try removing         serverconfig.LocalAddress = NetUtility.Resolve("localhost");
?

Comment: That did something, I got the dialog to allow/disallow internet access to a program. It still doesn't connect though.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your Windows Firewall?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I found your error:

In your `void StartClient()`, you are setting `message = server.ReadMessage()` in your while loop.

This should actually be `message = client.ReadMessage()`.

Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Lidgren.Network;
using System.Net;

namespace ChatClient
{
  class Program
  {
    static NetPeerConfiguration serverconfig;
    static NetPeerConfiguration clientconfig;
    static NetServer server;
    static NetClient client;

    static void Main()
    {
      NetPeerConfiguration serverconfig = new NetPeerConfiguration("chat");
      serverconfig.Port = 8081;
      serverconfig.MaximumConnections = 100;
      server = new NetServer(serverconfig);
      Thread serverthread = new Thread(StartServer);
      serverthread.Start();





      NetPeerConfiguration clientconfig = new NetPeerConfiguration("chat");
      clientconfig.AutoFlushSendQueue = false;
      client = new NetClient(clientconfig);
      Thread clientthread = new Thread(StartClient);
      clientthread.Start();
      AcceptConsoleInput();

    }

    static void StartServer()
    {
      server.Start();
      NetIncomingMessage message;

      while (true)
      {
        message = server.WaitMessage(500);
        if (message != null)
        {
          switch (message.MessageType)
          {
            case NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryRequest:
              NetOutgoingMessage response = server.CreateMessage();
              response.Write((byte)1); // Do I need to do this?
              server.SendDiscoveryResponse(response, message.SenderEndPoint);
              break;
            case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
              Console.WriteLine("(Server) Debug: " + message.ReadString());
              break;
            case NetIncomingMessageType.StatusChanged:
              NetConnectionStatus status = (NetConnectionStatus)message.ReadByte();

              string reason = message.ReadString();
              Console.WriteLine(NetUtility.ToHexString(message.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier) + " " + status + ": " + reason);

              if (status == NetConnectionStatus.Connected)
                Console.WriteLine("Remote hail: " + message.SenderConnection.RemoteHailMessage.ReadString());
              break;
            case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
              // incoming chat message from a client
              string chat = message.ReadString();


              // broadcast this to all connections, except sender
              List<NetConnection> all = server.Connections; // get copy
                                                            //all.Remove(message.SenderConnection);
              Console.WriteLine(all + "hello ");

              NetOutgoingMessage om = server.CreateMessage();
              server.SendMessage(om, all, NetDeliveryMethod.ReliableOrdered, 0);

              break;
            default:
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
              Console.WriteLine("(Server) Unrecognized message type! (" + message.MessageType + ")");
              break;
          }
        }
        server.Recycle(message);
      }
      Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    static void StartClient()
    {
      client.Start();
      client.DiscoverLocalPeers(8081);
      NetOutgoingMessage hail = client.CreateMessage("This is the hail message");


      NetIncomingMessage message;

      while (true)
      {
        message = client.WaitMessage(500);
        if (message != null) { 
        switch (message.MessageType)
        {
            case NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryResponse:
              Console.WriteLine("(Client) Got response from server.");
              client.Connect(message.SenderEndPoint, hail);
              Console.WriteLine("(Client) Attempting to connect to server...");
              break;

            case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
            Console.WriteLine(message.ReadString());
            break;
          case NetIncomingMessageType.ErrorMessage:
            Console.WriteLine(message.ReadString());
            break;
          case NetIncomingMessageType.WarningMessage:
            Console.WriteLine(message.ReadString());
            break;
          case NetIncomingMessageType.VerboseDebugMessage:
            Console.WriteLine(message.ReadString());
            break;
          case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
            string chat = message.ReadString();
            break;
          case NetIncomingMessageType.StatusChanged:
            NetConnectionStatus status = (NetConnectionStatus)message.ReadByte();
            Console.WriteLine(status.ToString());
            break;
          default:
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("(Client) Unrecognized message type! (" + message.MessageType + ")");
            break;
        }
      }
        client.Recycle(message);
      }
    }


    static void AcceptConsoleInput()
    {
      string input = Console.ReadLine();

      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
      {
        NetOutgoingMessage om = client.CreateMessage(input);
        client.SendMessage(om, NetDeliveryMethod.ReliableSequenced);
        client.FlushSendQueue();
      }

      AcceptConsoleInput();
    }
  }
}
```

I changed quite a bit so I could test for each part. I found the problem which is that almost immediately the message becomes null. I changed it to check continuously and keep checking even if it's null.